# What is causing messed up animations between blender and Jmonkey?

Tags: animation, blender, jmonkeyengine

Hi I have been looking for quite a while now on what is causing this problem and have come up completely empty.  I have a model that i have downloaded and rigged in blender and created some animations.  The animations look fine in blender (they still need a lot of work) but when i transfer them to jmonkey engine 3 they get all messed up and move in wrong directions.  I have fixed the weight paint so that there arent any vertices with more than 4 weights and i can export using the Ogre3D Exporter perfectly fine.  I have uploaded a video [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2y1O9LVhOGyVEdJM1V2S0dmUFU/view?usp=sharing) if someone could please figure out this problem for me i would be greatly appreciated.  Just to give a little description of the video.  The first set of animations are in blender and the second set is after i have exported the model using Ogre3D and imported it into Jmonkey Engine

Thanks You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was i was not properly applying the location rotation and scale to the model.  After i did that everything worked great.